# Problem with Array.map Javascript method and string with accents

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I noticed when i use ".map" on an array of strings with accent, there is a problem with the value of the current element.
I don't understand why the second condition is false.

```
const types: string[] = ['Fée']

types.map(type => {
   const str = 'Fée'

   if(str === type){
       console.log(`str true : ${str}`)
   } 

   if(type === 'Fée'){
       console.log('type true')
   } else {
       console.log(`type false : ${type}`)
   }
})
```

In the console :

```
"str true : Fée"
"type false : Fée"
```

Moreover, this strange "é" can be saved in a JSON file (UTF-8 encoding). Here VSCode don't highlights the middle row: [strange value in JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePrUK.png)

Comment: interesting the é in your array and if statement give different ascii codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your characters (`é`) is `e\u0301` or `\u0065\u0301`, a *LATIN SMALL LETTER E* [followed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) by [*COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent).

The other character (`é`) just `\u00e9`, a [*LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89).

You can tell that the strings are different also because of their `.length`.

To compare them, use [`.normalise()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize):

```js
const strings = ['Fée', 'Fée'];

console.log(strings[0] == strings[1]);
console.log(strings[0].normalize() == strings[1].normalize());
```

Answer (score 1):

With a page like https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html you can see that the two are not actually equivalent.
The Fée from `const str = 'Fée'` is `'\u0046\u0065\u0301\u0065'`
but the Fée from `if(type === 'Fée'){` is `'\u0046\u00e9\u0065'`.

To fix this you can use unicode normalization with [`String.prototype.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

```js
const types: string[] = ['Fée']

types.map(type => {
   type = type.normalize('NFC')
   const str = 'Fée'.normalize('NFC')

   if(str === type){
       console.log(`str true : ${str}`)
   } 

   if(type === 'Fée'){
       console.log('type true')
   } else {
       console.log(`type false : ${type}`)
   }
})
```